# Why am I shown so many "Problems" in Visual Studio Code, doing a routine tutorial?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I am following the instructions in this [official tutorial to Create a Web API with ASP.NET Core and VS Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-vsc).

I have the latest .NET Core SDK (v2.1.101) installed as well as the C# extension for VS Code.

Once I've opened the project folder in VS Code, I am shown over 100 issues in VS Code's "Problems" window. Please see image below. As I'm adding code to the project the number of problems increases.

Why am I shown so many problems and how can I resolve them?

Please note I've tried a `dotnet restore`, to no avail.

Also know that I have Bash on Windows Subsystem for Linux configured as the shell for the VS code terminal. (I also have the latest .NET Code SDK installed in WSL)

[image]

Comment: I've returned VS Code to the default terminal shell (cmd.exe) by removing this line from user settings: `    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\Sysnative\\bash.exe",` . Having restarted VS Code all "problems" are now gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per OP comment:

> I've returned VS Code to the default terminal shell (cmd.exe) by removing this line from user settings: `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\Sysnative\\bash.exe",` . Having restarted VS Code all "problems" are now gone